# Has China ever voted against the Palestinians during a UN resolution?

Tags: china, israel, palestine

> Beijing has sent its Middle East envoy, Zhai Jun, but neither Xi nor
> his foreign minister, Wang Yi, have visited the region since the
> outbreak of fighting.
>
> Xi has called for a ceasefire while Wang has said that the source of
> the conflict “lies in the fact that justice has not been done to the
> Palestinian people” and that the “collective punishment” of the
> Palestinians must come to an end.
>
> Such statements follow the basic Chinese playbook when conflict breaks
> out between Israelis and Palestinians, according to William Figueroa,
> an assistant professor at the University of Groningen who has
> conducted research on China’s relationship with Middle Eastern
> countries.
>
> **“They take a very cautious stance initially and then call for peace
> and condemn violence against civilians while primarily focusing on
> Palestinian grievances,” he told Al Jazeera.**

https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/11/6/china-takes-cautious-approach-to-diplomacy-over-israel-gaza-war

Has China ever voted against the Palestinians during a UN resolution? Like the article said, it seems that China is mostly pro-Palestine while trying to be somewhat fair to Israel at the same time instead of being 100% pro-Palestinian. So I was wondering if China ever voted against the interest of the Palestinian state during one of these UN resolutions.

Comment: By "China", do you include the Republic of China, or only the Peoples Republic?

Comment: Eg United Nations Security Council Resolution 69, admitting Israel to the UN.

Comment: @JamesK, Palestinians did not know they were Palestinians until 1967, how is that connected?

Comment: @dEmigOd - Nah, you know, I'm pretty sure  that at some point during the existence of British Mandatory Palestine or Palestina Prima, people had some idea of the existence of Palestinians. Of course, the same argument could be used to say that Israelis did not know that they were Israelis until 1948. It's interesting how many of the attempts to delegitimize (or affirm) Israeli and Palestinian identity at heart come from the same basic principles.

Comment: @Obie2.0, fair enough. did not claim a thing about Israeli. But the Q asks something specifically for Palestinians, that no one knew were Palestinians in 1948 (unless you provide a proof), so how is Republic of China vote in 1948 can be against the Palestinians? Did they knew the facts of future back then?

Comment: I take "Palestinian" to mean the Arabic peoples of that region (like everybody else does).  They weren't a state in 1948, but they were supported by (eg) Egypt, who voted against resolution 69.

Comment: The question could do with clarification. Does it refer to Security Council, General Assembly, or both? And what does "voting against the Palestinians" mean? Any support for Israel or Jews, or specifically a resolution opposing Palestinian self-determination or opposing condemnation of crimes against the Palestinians/criticising actions of Palestinians?

Comment: @Obie2.0 *I'm pretty sure that at some point during the existence of British Mandatory Palestine or Palestina Prima, people had some idea of the existence of Palestinians.* - the important point here is that Palestinians are identified with the British Mandate Palestine (at least UNRWA uses this definition as of 1948) - the people definitely lived there before 1920, but the ethnic/cultural/family borders didn't necessarily coincide with the Mandate.